# string in variable changes before sending through socket

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

I have the following scenario, a two socket connection (one acts as a server and the other one as a connection to a client).

I receive a command on the server socket and depending on the command I am building a string which I am sending to a client through the other socket.

This works pretty well if the commands are not arriving too fast, but in case I get command "test123" multiple times in short intervals it always happens a part of the next message to send is already saved to the string I am building.

I am sorting the commands I could receive this way:

```
if (command == "test123"){
                command_send = "asdf123";

                buf = string_a + "," + command_send + "," + string_b + "\n";
        }
else if (command == "123test"){
                command_send = "123asdf";

                buf = string_a + "," + command_send + "," + string_b + "\n";
        }
```

and so on, a few more else if are following....

then I convert the string to a char *:

```
const char *msg_s = buf.c_str();
```

Sending the message:

```
bytes_sent_s = send(socketfd_s, msg_s, len_s, 0)
```

In case the command test123 is sent 10 times my buf containes a part of the first command and in the middle a part of the command which should get send afterwards. My string to send then looks like "stringa,asdf123,asdf,stringb" or something like that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use local buffers (here local means no global as buffer, no member as buffer, but the least enclosing scope) and pass the buffer around (std::vector and move semantics, maybe)

Comment: What happens between the time you call `buf.c_str()` and when you actually call `send()`?  Is that string `buf` altered in any way?  If not, then why not just use `c_str()` directly in the `send()` call?  Why the intermediate step of assigning it to a `const char *`?

Comment: What you describe suggests that you are processing incoming commands asynchronously and re-using the same buffers each time.  While outbound data is still busy being sent, you are overwriting the buffer content prematurely.  So either stop processing commands asynchronously (read a command, then send a command, then read a command, then send a command, and so on), or else allocate a new set of buffers for each command, queue them (so they are sent serially and won't overlap) and free them once they are finished being used.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, no the buffer is not altered in any way, i also tried to send it the way you suggested, but no difference.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think thats the problem, you are right. Could you give me a short example how I could allocate a new set of buffers for each command and how to queue them? I am pretty new to c++

Comment: @RemyLebeau Use a container class and apply synchronization on the reads and writes to the container.  If you don't understand, please get familiar with doing this, as this is normal fare for processing data asynchronously.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15702064/need-a-good-solution-for-synchronized-read-write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the sending part, but the recieving. I am checking the recieved string now until a newline occours and now it works.

I have also implemented async communication using boost.